# How to disable go back button in Browser

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to limit user going back to the previous page,
It works but I can see previous page for millisecond and then current page reloads with
all API requests.

How can I prevent that behaviour?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

export default class Main extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // const history = useHistory();
    const history = createBrowserHistory();

    history.listen((newLocation, action) => {
      if (action === "PUSH") {
        if (
          newLocation.pathname !== this.currentPathname ||
          newLocation.search !== this.currentSearch
        ) {
          // Save new location
          this.currentPathname = newLocation.pathname;
          this.currentSearch = newLocation.search;

          // Clone location object and push it to history
          history.push({
            pathname: newLocation.pathname,
            search: newLocation.search,
          });
        }
      } else {
        // Send user back if they try to navigate back
        history.go(1);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Page1} />
            <Route path="/main/page2" component={Page2} />
            <Route path="/main/page3" component={Page3} />
            <Route path="/main/page4" component={Page4} />
            <Route path="/main/page5" component={Page5} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try set the routes `replace`:

```
        <Route path="/main/page2" component={Page2} replace={true}/>
        <Route path="/main/page3" component={Page3} replace={true}/>
        <Route path="/main/page4" component={Page4} replace={true}/>
        <Route path="/main/page5" component={Page5} replace={true}/>
```

Comment: Note that this will completely disable navigation buttons

Comment: didn't help, same result